# Tunnel for sending a request through a proxy in dart

Tags: dart, proxy, binance, cryptocurrency

I wrote a dart code that creates a tunnel to connect to binance api through a proxy. Works with dynamic proxies, but not with static ones

I'm trying to create a method that proxies a request to binance api through an http proxy server.
The code is below :

```
void main() async {
  final uri = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.binance.com/sapi/v1/asset/get-funding-asset');
  final transport = await connectTunnel('185.142.98.232', 29130, uri.host,
      username: 'Pbt5MoAU89ph', password: 'itsallgood.man');

  final payload = jsonEncode({'key': 'value'});
  final contentLength = utf8.encode(payload).length;

  final headers = [
    Header.ascii(':method', 'POST'),
    Header.ascii(':path', uri.hasQuery ? uri.path + '?' + uri.query : uri.path),
    Header.ascii(':scheme', uri.scheme),
    Header.ascii(':authority', uri.host),
    Header.ascii('content-type', 'application/json'),
    Header.ascii('content-length', contentLength.toString()),
  ];

  final stream = transport.makeRequest(headers, endStream: false);
  stream.outgoingMessages.add(DataStreamMessage(utf8.encode(payload)));
  await stream.outgoingMessages.close();

  final bodyStream = StreamController<List<int>>();
  utf8.decoder.bind(bodyStream.stream).listen(print);

  await for (final message in stream.incomingMessages) {
    if (message is HeadersStreamMessage) {
      for (final header in message.headers) {
        final name = utf8.decode(header.name);
        final value = utf8.decode(header.value);
        print('Header: $name: $value');
      }
    } else if (message is DataStreamMessage) {
      bodyStream.add(message.bytes);
      if (message.endStream) {
        await bodyStream.close();
      }
    } else {
      print('Incoming message: $message');
    }
  }
  if (!bodyStream.isClosed) {
    await bodyStream.close();
  }
  await transport.finish();
}

Future<ClientTransportConnection> connectTunnel(
  String proxyHost,
  int proxyPort,
  String targetHost, {
  required String username,
  required String password,
  int targetPort = 443,
}) async {
  try {
    final proxy = await Socket.connect(
      proxyHost,
      proxyPort,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
    );
    const CRLF = '\r\n';
    proxy
      ..write('CONNECT $targetHost:$targetPort HTTP/1.1') // request line
      ..write(CRLF);
    proxy.write('Host: $targetHost:$targetPort'); // header
    proxy.write(CRLF);
    final authString = base64.encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    proxy.write('Proxy-Authorization: Basic $authString');
    proxy.write(CRLF);
    proxy.write(CRLF);
    final completer = Completer<bool>.sync();
    final sub = proxy.listen(
      (event) {
        final response = ascii.decode(event);
        final lines = response.split(CRLF);
        // status line
        final statusLine = lines.first;
        if (statusLine.startsWith('HTTP/1.1 200')) {
          print(statusLine);
          completer.complete(true);
        } else {
          completer.completeError(statusLine);
        }
      },
      onError: completer.completeError,
    );
    await completer.future; // established
    sub.pause();

    // ignore: close_sinks
    final socket = await SecureSocket.secure(
      proxy,
      host: targetHost,
      supportedProtocols: const ['h2'],
    );
    // ignore: newline-before-return
    return ClientTransportConnection.viaSocket(socket);
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    print('SocketException: $e');
    rethrow;
  } on HttpException catch (e) {
    print('HttpException: $e');
    rethrow;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

In the response, the server response should come, as well as the response headers.

When I change the proxy to dynamic - the request is sending correctly(bought it here https://packetstream.io/).

```
final transport = await connectTunnel('54.85.190.239', 31112, uri.host,
      username: 'moneytrain', password: 'obXG397wDMv55YyY_country-Brazil');
```

there is no answer with a static proxy, which is in the original code (tried to buy a few proxies in other services)

where did i make a mistake?

Comment: Why do you need a proxy?  Can't you get to the API directly?  My spider-sense is tingling.

Comment: There is no need to use a proxy to get the balance, but for some other requests it is mandatory to specify the ip address in the binance personal account, and therefore I want to use a proxy so that I myself can physically be in other places

Comment: This isn't a discussion area :) but why don't you just rent a $5/month DigitalOcean box with a fixed IP, and load up a proxy relay there, like OpenVPN?